# How do I create a Login System in Django Using Sessions?

Tags: django, session, authentication, django-authentication

I am trying to create a website which is authenticated by a custom login. But I have a custom Model for users. How do I authenticate my Website from anonymous Users. Is it possible to create login systems using based on sessions. Actually this is my first django project. Please Guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While login, after checking username and password create a session in which set their user object or it's object id in it. In this case i kept user id.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if (Users.objects.filter(username = request.GET.get("uname"), password = request.GET.get("upswd"))).exists():
            user = Users.objects.get(username = request.GET.get("uname"), password = request.GET.get("upswd"))
            request.session["user"] = user.id
            # request.session.set_expiry(10)
            # it shows home page
            return render(request,"home.html")
    #it shows again login page
    return render(request,"Login.html")
```

only in login page you will set session, In remaining you will check whether page contains that session or not.For example, in after login in home page you should check whether request contains user session or not.

```
if request.session.has_key("user"):
    userid = request.session["user"]
    #displaying all items in database
    context={"items":Products.objects.all()}
    return render(request,"home.html",context)
```

Comment: How can I set in every page is user is logged or not?? Thanks In advance

Comment: @JIs ```from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required``` and use the decorator on your view methods like ```@login_required``` when your user is not logged in, he will be redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a POST form instead of a GET request as against the answer above. Also, instead of querying for username and password against your database, use `authenticate()` function.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

if request.POST:
    if login_form.is_valid():
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user: 
            login(request, user)
        # do something or redirect
```

You don't need to set the user id in the session object, to retrieve the currently logged in user, use `request.user`

Comment: i think we don't need to create session in django if we are using login function as it automatically saves the user_id in session.