# How to solve a attribute error in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to log in a user but I am getting an attribute error.

Here is my **forms.py**:

```
class Login(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=250)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def login_user(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user in User.objects.all():
            login(self, user)
        else:
            return render(self, 'todoapp/waiting_2.html')
```

Here is my **views.py**:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = Login(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            login_form.login_user()
            login_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'todoapp/waiting_2.html')
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': Login()})
```

When I fill in the fields and try to log in, I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError at /login/

'Login' object has no attribute 'session'
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/practice/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/practice/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/practice/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/assignment/todoapp/views.py" in login_user
  48.             login_form.login_user(request)

File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/assignment/todoapp/forms.py" in login_user
  27.             login(self, request, user)

File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/practice/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  126.     if SESSION_KEY in request.session:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /login/
Exception Value: 'Login' object has no attribute 'session'
```

Comment: Can you show your full traceback?

Comment: Create a session after logged in. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668969/how-do-i-create-a-login-system-in-django-using-sessions

Comment: render method inside form  i think needs to be fixed

Comment: @Sanip Edited the question with Traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors here. The main one of attempting to render within the form login_user method. Apart from anything else, you attempt to pass the `self` as the request parameter to render, which mages no sense.

Remove all of that if/else. You don't need to render; but also note that your if condition is needlessly inefficient. If you get a user, it's necessarily a User.

Finally, the actual cause of your error, where again you are trying to pass self in the place of a request, but this time as the parameter to `login`. That code belongs in the view.

And finally, the form is not a ModelForm, so there is no save method.

So, form:

```
def login_user(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    return authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```

and view:

```
    if login_form.is_valid():
        user = login_form.login_user()
        if user:
            login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
```

Although at this point you may as well move all that logic to the view.

Comment: Showing an error at `user=login_form.login_user()` that `Parameter 'request' unfilled`

Comment: It worked now. I forgot to remove the `request` from the form function. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`login()` get as first argument the request, you call it with the form as first argument. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login